# Is this the appropriate way to define a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models here. Property and User. 
I need to create a one to many relationships here. One user can have many properties. Each property has one user.

I have to the corresponding model linked in the models like so.

> Property.cs

```
public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId {get; set}
}
```

> User.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public Property Property { get; set; }
}
```

Will that do the job, or do I need to write an entity builder in my onmodelcreate method in the data context file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've created here is a one-to-one relationship. To make this a one-to-many relationship, you will need to create a collection of Properties on the User model:

```
public class Property
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId {get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; } = new List<UserRole>();

    // This must be a collection
    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; } = new List<Property>();
}
```

Entity Framework will automatically create the relationship given the code above (and will do so for other entities in your model, as long as you obey specific [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions)), or you can explicitly define it using [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations) or the [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fluent-api). It is recommended to explicitly define your relationships, as well as other model properties (e.g. keys, string field lengths). This will help to clarify these attributes in the code, and ensure that Entity Framework defines the model in the manner you intend.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any advantageous of defining the relationship yourself using the Fluent API vs letting entity framework take care of it,

Comment: See my update. I prefer to explicitly define the model, and I recommend Fluent API.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I have a question about the code. Why do you declare a collection and then assign a new list afterwards?

Comment: It's useful to initialize the collection when the User class is instantiated so that you can immediately add items to it. It is not strictly necessary, as you can always assign a new list instance after creating the new user object, but doing it this way is likely to prevent bugs, e.g.: `var u = new User(); u.Properties.Add(...); // This will throw an exception if User.Properties has not been assigned a collection object`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want your `User` to have many properties you need to set the `Property` property into a collection. Otherwise this would be a one-to-one relationship.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

And since you want to use your property collection right away you need to initialize it in a constructor.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public User() {
         Properties = new List<Property>();
    }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```